# Can't get GRASS r.water.outlet to work

Tags: grass-gis, watershed, r.watershed

I'm new to GRASS. 
We want to delineate a watershed using the LIDAR data we have our hands on.
I tried to follow several procedures to do so, but despite all my efforts, I can only get it to select a single cell out of the DEM.

I'm using GRASS 7.0.5

What I've done:

- Created the DEM using r.patch and the necessary tiles
- Defined my work region (g.region)
- r.patch the DEM to fix the bridges
- Used r.watershed to create the Accumulation and Drainage direction layers (tried with 0, 5k and 50k thresholds)
- Used the Drainage layer to r.water.outlet

While I eventually get a result, it is only a single pixel, although I made sure to be very (VERY) precise (5 digits precise...) on the stream coordinates. Picture of the output.

[image]

I believe part of the problem is that my DEM is huge... but I find it hard to believe that I'm the only one using this kind of data.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the diagonal line in the image above? Note that the outlet coordinates for `r.water.outlet` must be on the stream network created by **r.watershed**.

Comment: The line (diagonal) is my stream network, but my vector layer. I indeed made the mistake of not using the stream generated by r.watershed. I'll give it a try and come back with the results, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentionned by Micha, my problem was that I was using my original stream vector layer instead of the one generated by r.watershed.

So to be clear:
- With r.watershed, create both Drainage direction and Stream (at least)
- With r.water.outlet, use the Stream raster layer generated this way to pinpoint precisely your outlet and the Drainage direction layer as raster input for computation

Comment: you can mark your answer as accepted 
https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/